# Inconsistent datatypes: expected - got - ORA-00932 while trying to use XMLTable

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, xml-parsing

I'm trying to query a table where one of the columns has a large amount of data in nested XML. I've been using the `EXTRACTVALUE()` function to surface the 1-to-1 fields but there are a number of 1-to-many fields as well which need a different approach.

After some searching I found the `XMLTABLE()` function which seemed to be fit for purpose, however I'm getting an error message of inconsistent datatypes and can't work around it even though the column datatype is XMLTYPE.

***Database version is Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit***

Here is a sample of the XML:

```xml
<QuoteData>
    <DataCat1>
        <ProductDistribution>
            <Details>
                <Name>Product1</Name>
                <Amount>24</Amount>
                <Price>100</Price>
            </Details>
            <Details>
                <Name>Product2</Name>
                <Amount>50</Amount>
                <Price>200</Price>  
            </Details>
        </ProductDistribution>
    </DataCat1>
</QuoteData>
```

My query is:

```sql
select 

q.PROD_NAME,
q.PRICE

from DB_PROD_TBL r, xmltable('/QuoteData'
    passing r.PROD_LINE_DATA 
    columns
     PROD_NAME varchar2(50) path '/DataCat1/ProductDistribution/Details/Name',
     PRICE number path '/DataCat1/ProductDistribution/Details/Price')q;
```

Comment: What data type is `prod_line_data` - I'm guessing it's a CLOB, from the error you're getting? (If it was a `varchar2` you'd get ORA-19279 I think; and if it's XMLType you wouldn't get an error but would just gets nulls in your output...)

Comment: Your query works if it's already XMLType. (Well, it gets a single row with nulls, but doesn't error). [Demo showing that and query with fixed paths](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=5320a623cea1c2647d81ed8ad99dedac).

Comment: I can't replicate this in 12.1.0.2 or [18c](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8ca5661467b725db24b9983b2a599b4a) either. And I can't see any known issues like this. Not sure what I'm doing differently I'm afraid.

Comment: Interestingly when I change the output column format within the XMLTABLE() function to XMLTYPE it doesn't return any error message, but doesn't return any rows either. I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Nope, can't reproduce that either. You should still get a single row with null values. Are you sure the error is coming from the standalone query you posted - it's not really part of a larger query, or being fed into something that throws the error?